# Search and show duplicate data php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[image: table]

I want to search and execute the data with the same orderid  . Unfortunately it says

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Workshop1\admin\ordersearch.php on line 114

```
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    // id to search
    $Orderid = $_POST['Orderid'];


    // connect to mysql
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","workshop1");

    // mysql search query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE Orderid =  $Orderid  ;";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);


    // if id exist 
    // show data in inputs
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {?>

                            <td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;' align='center'><?php echo $result["Orderid"];?></td>
                            <td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;' align='center'><?php echo $result["productid"];?></td>
                            <td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;' align='center'><?php echo $result["price"];?></td>
                            <td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;' align='center'><?php echo $result["quantity"];?></td>
                            <td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;' align='center'><?php echo $result["custid"];?></td>

<?php


      }  
    }

    // if the id not exist
    // show a message and clear inputs
    else {
        echo "Undifined ID";

    }


    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($connect);

}
```

Comment: Your fetching data into `$row` but trying to use something like `$result["Orderid"]` - change it to `$row["Orderid"]`

Comment: Thank you so much ! @NigelRen

Answer (score 2):

you must write your code like this because if you don't it will recognize `$Orderid` as 
a string.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE Orderid = '" . $Orderid. "' limit 1 ";
```

and change this

```
<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;' align='center'>
    <?php echo $row["Orderid"];?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are store data in loop using `$row` variable so that you need to use `$row['orderId'];` if you print data in loop for ex. `print_r($row);`